# Partitioning by id in another table. Bigquery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, partitioning, partition-by

I have users in that sometimes are registred twice with the same value for pn "Phonenumber". Knowing that pn PhoneNumber is the same I know that they should be the same rid "RegisterID". Trouble is that pn is not very reliable either and sometimes shows null values. How to do this partition?

I want to do something like this

```
WITH a AS (
  SELECT 1 AS dt, 1 AS rid, 1 AS pn, 1 AS cnt
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS dt, 1 AS rid, 1 AS pn, 1 AS cnt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS dt, 2 AS rid, 1 AS pn, 1 AS cnt
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS dt, 2 AS rid, 1 AS pn, 1 AS cnt
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS dt, 2 AS rid, NULL AS pn, 1 AS cnt
)
SELECT dt, 
       COALESCE(MIN(rid) OVER (PARTITION BY pn), rid) AS rid, 
       pn, 
       SUM(cnt) AS cnt
FROM a 
GROUP BY dt, pn, rid
```

And get a result that looks like this:

dt rid pn cnt

1  1  1  1

2  1  1  2

3  1  1  2

Answer (score 0):

Fist find to each `rig` the largest `pn`. We ignore the connections over several phone numbers. Then we search for the smallest `rid` for each largest  `pn`. If the largest `pn` is `null` then each `rig` stays for itself. Please see the `(PARTITION BY ifnull(''||pn,''||rid))`. Last we join this info the the main table.

```
WITH a AS (
  SELECT 1 AS dt, 1 AS rid, 1 AS pn, 1 AS cnt
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS dt, 1 AS rid, 1 AS pn, 1 AS cnt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS dt, 2 AS rid, 1 AS pn, 1 AS cnt
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS dt, 2 AS rid, 1 AS pn, 1 AS cnt
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS dt, 2 AS rid, NULL AS pn, 1 AS cnt
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 55 AS dt, 5 AS rid, NULL AS pn, 1 AS cnt
    UNION ALL 
  SELECT 66 AS dt, 6 AS rid, NULL AS pn, 1 AS cnt
),
B as (
  Select rid, max(pn) as pn 
  from A 
  group by 1
  ),
  C as (
    Select 
    pn, rid,
    min(rid) OVER (PARTITION BY ifnull(''||pn,''||rid)) as rid_main,
    count(1) as counts
    from B 
    group by 1,2
    order by 1,2
    )

  Select rid_main, A.*
  from A 
  left join C
  on A.rid=C.rid 
  #group by 1
```